# Error " ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE" when using npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I tried to create a new NodeJs project, when i ran "npm init" the package.json was created successfully but when I tried to run "npm install express" it showed "npm ERR! code ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE". I am not able to run npm install without getting this error.

I tried to install other packages, i tried sudo, and I removed npm/node and reinstalled nvm/node but it is still the same.

Thank you for your help !

```
npm install express
npm ERR! code ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE
npm ERR! The value of "err" is out of range. It must be a negative integer. Received 536870212

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2019-09-18T14_49_07_222Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Comment: @Sagar Chaudhary, thanks that came from the version of node, I was using 12.10.0 and when I came back to 10.16.0 this error was gone !

Comment: Yes, the error was due to node version

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a mismatch between your versions of Node and NPM.
This can occur when one is updated without the other.

To prevent these issues, use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your Node version:

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash

# Example: Selecting Node v13 
# For complete list of available versions run `nvm ls-remote`

nvm install 13
nvm use 13
```

This will select matching versions of Node and NPM.

Comment: If anyone has this issue and is confused because they haven't updated either of these things, or their versions appear to match, be sure you havent disallowed your Node (version) from making network requests in LittleSnitch/Lulu.

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by a the most recent version of node which was 12.10.0, when I installed and used the 10.16.0 version of node, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into something very similar with react native - metro and it seems I just had to deactivate my firewall LULU.